# Как добавить сторонние файлы в command-line утилиту на Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, mac

День добрый.
Пишу консольную утилиту на *Objective-C* (под Mac OS X). Внезапно стало необходимо добавить к этой утилите пару-тройку *property list*'ов. Но, так как это не GUI приложение *(с отдельной папкой для подобного рода вещей)*, а просто один бинарник, то как добавить в него сторонние файлы - не знаю (да и мне кажется, что это вообще невозможно).
Можно, конечно, их содержание в константу запихать, но это не по Фен-Шую.  
Еще вариант - запаковать утилиту вместе с этими файлами в установочный пакет, который их запишет, например, в ~/Library/MyAppFolder/. А уж потом просто оттуда их считывать.

В общем, буду очень благодарен, если кто подскажет еще варианты решения проблемы. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, для консольных приложений возможны несколько вариантов.

> *Упаковываем сам бинарник и все дополнительные файлы в установочный
> пакет, а затем уже из самого
> исполняемого файла работаем с этими
> ресурсами по заранее известным путям.*

**Плюсы**: 
 - удобно для текстовых файловизображенийзвуков и т.д 
**Минусы**:
 -  требует установки пакета пользователем (т.е. нужны права администратора);
 -  при необходимости использовать сторонние фреймворки такой способ не подходит, так как они подключаются к проекту по относительным путям (а путь куда они будут скопированы при установке предусмотреть невозможно);

---

> *Вручную создаем bundle-папку для приложения*

**Плюсы**:
 - не требует установки;
 - возможность создать любую структуру хранения файлов (например, папки Resources, Frameworks,  Binaries и т.д);
 - *все* файлы доступны по одним и тем же путям, независимо от того, где расположена папка с приложением;
**Минусы**:
 - при первом запуске приложения необходимо (ну, почти всегда необходимо) будет создать символьную ссылку на ваш исполняемый файл, например, в /usr/bin  - чтобы приложение можно было запускать из комадной строки (а для этого такого рода приложения и существуют).

Answer (score 1):

Листы длинные? Может, при первом запуске закачать значения в NSDictionary, а потом выгрузить с помощью - (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag? Я бы так сделал.

Comment: Ну да, это, собственно, и есть один из вариантов, что я предлагал. Для текстовых файлов - похоже самый простой способ. Однако, я бы хотел узнать какие еще есть способы.

Comment: Так это по-моему и есть самый простой путь решения